# Running phpize shows Cannot find config.m4

Tags: imagemagick, centos

```
tar -zxvf ImageMagick*.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick*
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

running: `phpize`
Cannot find `config.m4`.
Make sure that you run `'/usr/bin/phpize'` in the top level source directory of the module

Answer (score 2):

What about this? also it could be possible config.m4 isn't exist where you are running phpize.

```
./configure
phpize
make
make install
```